# Ability to read and eval() any arbitrary function / lambda from JSON config file

Tags: python, json, lambda

I am looking for a way to a user to enter any arbitrary python formula, store the formula in a text file or a JSON file, then have Python read the formula and apply the transformation to a data frame.  My original requirement is to have a frontend web UI where the user can specify any transformation rules / scripts / formulas.

For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'state_full': ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'American Samoa'],
'state_abbrev': ['Ala.', 'Alaska', np.nan],
'state_postal': ['AL', 'AK', 'AS']}, index=[0, 1, 2])

df['state_abbrev'].str.upper()   # This works, but I need to read the formula from a file
```

Want ability to read any arbitrary lambda function from a config file in JSON:

```
lambda_transform_str = "str.upper()"   
df['state_abbrev'].eval(lambda_transform_str)
```

Encountered Error:
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'eval'

Comment: Why would you want to do this? If you allow any arbitrary inputs then you run the risk of destroying your own system.

Comment: Honestly, unless I'm grossly misunderstanding, this seems like _the_ worst idea. "... have a frontend web UI where the user can specify any transformation rules / scripts / formulas." None of your code deals with the frontend... the part that will be repeatedly hammered by all the ne'er do wells that will destroy everything. Have you read http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html

Answer (score 1):

The `eval` function in Python isn't a method attached to strings; it's a globally available function. You should be able to call it like:

```
eval(..)
```

If you're trying to transform `df['state_abbrev']` according to the contents of `lambda_transform_str`, you need to approach this problem another way.

```
eval('"{}".upper()'.format(df['state_abbrev']))
```

This has limitations obviously since you have to ensure that your textual functions are all compatible with the `str` type, but that's an implementation detail I'll leave up to you.

As @martineau pointed out in the comments, be wary of using `eval`. It can expose codebases to serious security vulnerabilities.

Comment: It's also dangerous to use on any untrusted input.

Comment: It definitely can be. That's a whole other discussion. I'll leave those concerns to the discretion of the OP.

Comment: Fine, but it's worth mentioning every time you propose using it as the answer to a question. Many folks are unaware of the issue and shouldn't use it without knowing about it. You won't give a knife to a child for the first time without warning them about its dangers would you?